# How to see Sparkline for Mutual Funds using googlefinance?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

In Google sheets when I try to plot the mutual fund price for the last one year using `sparkline` function, I keep getting an error.

> When evaluating `GOOGLEFINANCE`, the query for the symbol: `DSP_TAX_SAVE_9IDIGA` returned no data.

The Code that I am using to plot is as follows:

```
=sparkline(GoogleFinance(A1, "price", today()-365, today(), "daily"))
```

A1 can be any mutual fund symbol example `DSP_TAX_SAVE_9IDIGA`

It used to work well in the past but has stopped working since last few months and I have searched extensively for a solution but not able to find anything. Can someone please help here.

**Note 1:** `DSP_TAX_SAVE_9IDIGA` is a valid symbol

**Note 2:** I am facing the same issue with all the Mutual funds with respect to `sparkline` and morningstarrating